# Will Microsoft Money Sunset version run under windows 10

Tags: microsoft-money

I tried Windows 10 but when trying to install Microsoft Money Plus Sunset, the system requested installation of IE 6 and above. Is IE available under Windows 10? if yes, can be set as default? if yes will then Microsoft Money Plus run under Windows 10?

Comment: The software you are trying to use is not compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: [IE is included in W10](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-find-internet-explorer-windows-10-if-you-really-need-it) but as suggested by Ramhound that Money software is not compatible with W10.

Comment: I THINK the problem is that money can't cope with IE having a version string that is more then 15 char long.    The build number of IE on windows 10 is large....